# MySQl pivot dynamic data

Tags: mysql, pivot, mariadb

I need some help trying the get the following output in MYSQL.
Given the fact that I do **not** have rights to create a temporary table 
how can I output the following rows using the **MySQL** syntax

This is a sampling of the data in sql

```
            Create table #Temp
            ( Category varchar(20)
            ,CreatedMonth int
            ,NumberOfIssues int
            )
            Insert into  #Temp
            SELECT 'Access  Support',9,28
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Ecom  Support',9,76
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Inhouse ',9,7
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Access  Support',10,59
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'Server Support',10,23
```

My desired Resulset in MySQL is 
**Category     Month_9       Month_10**

```
            The first row having the values of [Access  Support],28,59
            The second row having the values of [Ecom  Support],76,0
            The third row having the values of [Inhouse ],7,0
            The fourth row having the values of [Server Support],0,23
```

There are at least 30 categories defined.

Thank you for any suggestions.
SD

Comment: Unclear -- The `UNION` of the several `SELECTs` will output what you asked for.  Why do you think you need a temp?

Answer (score 0):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/group_concat/)

```
SELECT Category, GROUP_CONCAT(NumberOfIssues) FROM yourtable WHERE CreatedMonth BETWEEN 9 AND 10 GROUP BY Category
```